# Mini-GMP Arduino printing

Tags: c, arduino, gmp

I am trying to use the Mini-GMP in the Arduino IDE, it seems that there is no implemented way such as gmp_printf to print to the Serial monitor. It seems that there is also no "official" documentation for the mini-gmp.

How would one print the numbers?

To specify, I am trying to implement RSA 512, or similar on an Arduino MEGA 2560, and it seemed that the mini GMP was an obvious choice. Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: `mpz_out_str` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct, mini-gmp has no gmp_printf functions, look at the `mini-gmp\mini-gmp.h` declarations, its the most *official* you can get of mini-gmp, but as Marc Glisse pointed out, there's the `mpz_out_str` function which should print to the output stream if you specifiy it in the first parameter, and you can also specify the *base* which is the base radix output. But, by the code, it only works if you have some kind of file std IO on your system (`stdio.h`, etc.).

Also, you can use in the [Integer Import and Export Functions](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Import-and-Export#index-mpz_005fexport) the `mpz_export` function, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551496/convert-mpz-t-to-binary-representation), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280359/send-array-of-mpz-t-over-mpi/5280393#5280393), and [here](https://machinecognitis.github.io/Math.Gmp.Native/html/c9d371c8-8c16-77a3-2c47-8edae05276c5.htm).